# duplex operation between two processes using named pipes in c#

Tags: c#, named-pipes, duplex

I am trying to use named pipes to communicate between a server and a client process on the same machine. server sends a message to client, client does something with it and returns a result, and server is supposed to get the result.

here is the code for server:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;

class PipeServer
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer =
            new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NamedPipeServerStream object created.");

            // Wait for a client to connect
            Console.Write("Waiting for client connection...");
            pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

            Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");
            try
            {
                // Read user input and send that to the client process.
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeServer))
                {
                    sw.AutoFlush = true;
                    Console.Write("Enter text: ");
                    sw.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer))
                {
                    // Display the read text to the console 
                    string temp;

                    // Wait for result from the client. 
                    while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[CLIENT] Echo: " + temp);
                    }
                }

            }
            // Catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is 
            // broken or disconnected.
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code for client:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;

class PipeClient
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient =
            new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
        {

            // Connect to the pipe or wait until the pipe is available.
            Console.Write("Attempting to connect to pipe...");
            pipeClient.Connect();

            Console.WriteLine("Connected to pipe.");
            Console.WriteLine("There are currently {0} pipe server instances open.",
               pipeClient.NumberOfServerInstances);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient))
            {
                // Display the read text to the console
                string temp;
                while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Received from server: {0}", temp);
                }
            }


            // send the "result" back to the Parent process.
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient))
            {
                sw.AutoFlush = true;
                sw.WriteLine("Result");
            }

            pipeClient.WaitForPipeDrain();

        }
        Console.Write("Press Enter to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

But in the server code, on line  pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();  I get an ObjectDisposedException and it says "cannot access a closed pipe."

I also get the same error in the client code on when setting sw.AutoFlush to true.

Basically I couldn't find an example of duplex named pipe in c#. I either need that, or an example of anonynous pipe, with two pipes one for reading and one for writting between a parent and a child process.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Doesn't disposing the `StreamWriter` also close the underlying stream (that is, your `pipeServer`)?

Comment: WCF running on top of named pipes will save you a ton of work.

Comment: where can I see an example please?

Comment: If anyone else has trouble with this, try removing ALL the using blocks (i.e., just StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient);) - this worked for me and I figure the garbage collector will handle proper disposal when I close the applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Problem is the using block of the `StreamWriter`, which will close the underlying Stream (which is your pipe here). If you don't use that block it should work.

You could do the following:

```
using (var pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(pipeServer))
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(pipeServer))
{
   // ... Your code ..
}
```

As Johannes Egger pointed out, the `StreamWriter` flushes the stream on `Dispose()`, so the `StreamWriter` should be disposed first and thus be the inner-most object to dispose.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. there was one more problem in the code, that Reads were taking place in a while loop and as a result there was a deadlock, changed the while to If and it works fine now.

Comment: In my case it was important that the writer is disposed after the reader because the writer did a flush when disposed, but when the reader is disposed first the pipe is disposed as well and the writer can't flush.