# Sending arguments to a child process using named pipe

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I have a parent program (Server) and a child program (client), and the two can have full-duplex communication with each other using named pipes: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833202/duplex-operation-between-two-processes-using-named-pipes-in-c-sharp)

My actual client and server are a bit more complicated. My client needs some input parameters(objects) in order to do its work, so I was thinking to send these using the pipe that I have created. Some people have mentioned WCF. This is the first time have heard of WCF. How can I send my objects through a named pipe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually using WCF is the best way to send objects between two processes. Even you can still using pipes and named pipes for it.
I recommend you [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805489) book for further knowledge.

Anyway if you want to use pipes between two processes to send and receive objects you must serialize them.
This is, convert the objects to be sent in arrays of bytes, xml, or soap format.
There are tons of examples in the web showing how to send data through sockets and pipes. Both are very similar.

I suggest you to create an independent assembly with classes that will be sent and received. That assembly must be referenced by both processes.

I hope this helps you.